# Nilpotence and conjugacy in $M(p,\mathbb F_p)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, finite-fields, nilpotence

I have to solve the following problem:

> Characterize matrices $X\in M(p,\mathbb F_p)$ (note that $p$ is the dimension and the characteristic of the field) such that there exists $Y$ with the property $YX-XY=X$.

The text is not clear, since it doesn't explain whether $Y$ must be in $M(p,\mathbb F_p)$ or just in $M(p,\overline{\mathbb F_p})$.

In the case $K=\mathbb C$ (instead of $\mathbb F_p$) and the dimension is $n$, a solution makes use of the fact that, if $char\ K=0$, $X$ is nilpotent if and only if $tr(X^i)=0$ for all $i>0$, and it turns out that such $Y\in M(p,\mathbb C)$ exists if and only if $X$ is nilpotent. In fact, if $X$ is nilpotent one finds the correct $Y$ for its Jordan form $J$, where $X=SJS^{-1}$:
$$\tilde Y=diag(n-1,n-2,...,0)$$
$$\tilde YJ-J\tilde Y=J$$
 and the statement follows easily by considering $Y=S\tilde YS^{-1}$; conversely, if such $Y$ exists all $tr(X^i)$ are $0$, then $X$ is nilpotent.

But in characteristic $p$ that fact isn't true (it is true, for example, if $0\in Sp(X)$; on the contrary, if $X=Id_p$, $tr(X^i)=0$ for all $i$ but $X$ is not nilpotent). Worse, even though $\tilde Y\in M(p,\mathbb F_p)$, $Y$ could be in $M(p,\overline{\mathbb F_p})\setminus M(p,\mathbb F_p)$ (or am I wrong?).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would assume in this case that you're meant to consider $Y \in \Bbb F_p$, but I'm sure that considering first the case of $Y \in \overline{\Bbb F_p}$ gets you most of the way there.  We may be able to state from the structure of $Y$ that we can take entries from $\Bbb F_p$.

Comment: So, any $X$ for which such a $Y$ exists satisfies $\sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j^i = 0$ for all $i$, but this tells us surprisingly little.  We can't even deduce that $X$ is invertible in the usual way since there's noting wrong (in terms of trace) with the equation
$$
X^{-1}YX - Y = I
$$

Comment: We have $p_X(\lambda_i)=0$ for all eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ ($p_X=\sum_j a_j x^j$ is the characteristic polynomial), and therefore $\sum_{\lambda_i\neq 0} \sum_j a_i \lambda_i^j=0$, i.e. $\sum tr(X^j)=-da_0$, where we can take $d$ as the number of nonzero eigenvalues of $X$. On the other way, if $Y$ exists, it is easily verified that $tr(X^j)=0$ for all $j$. Then if $char\ X=0$ then $d=0$, if $char K=p$ then $d=0$ or $d=p$. Then $X$ is either nilpotent or invertible.

Comment: If $X$ is invertible the equation you wrote gives us that the eigenvalues are $\lambda,\lambda+1,...,\lambda+p-1$ for some $\lambda$ (since the eigenvalues of $X^{-1}YX$ are the same of $Y$...), but then, as you observed, it doesn't appear obvious how to continue.

Comment: How did you find that $d = 0$ or $d = p$?  Perhaps I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Sorry. I have forgotten to write an important detail. $p_X$ is not the characteristic polynomial, but only the product of $(x-\lambda_i)$, where $\lambda_i\neq 0$. This gives us the formula above, _with $a_o\neq 0$_. Therefore $p\mid d$ and, since $d\leq p$ (dimension) $d=0,p$.

Comment: I still don't understand how you concluded that either $X$ has $0$ as its only eigenvalue ($X$ is nilpotent) or $X$ in invertible.

Comment: Notable observation:
$$
YX^2 - X^2Y = \frac 12 [(YX - XY)X + X(YX - XY)] = X^2
$$
I think that if $X$ is such that there exists a satisfactory $Y$, then so is $X^k$, and the same $Y$ will work for each power of $X$.

Comment: By definition of $d$, if $d=p$, the eigenvalues of $X$ are all nonzero, and then it is invertible. If $d=0$, all eigenvalues are equal to zero. Or is there any error in that? Thank you by the way for your help.

Comment: I had missed the earlier statement
$$
\sum tr(X^j)=-da_0
$$
that's what I'm not understanding.  Upon closer inspection, I still don't see how you got this.

Comment: $\sum_{j\geq 1} a_j\lambda_i^j=-a_0$ for all $i$ such that $\lambda_i\neq 0$. So $\sum_{\lambda_i\neq 0}\sum_{j\geq 1}a_i\lambda_i^j=-da_0$, and then, exchanging sums, $\sum_{j\geq 1}\sum_{\lambda_i\neq 0}a_j\lambda_i^j=\sum_{j\geq 1}a_j tr(X^j)=-da_0$. I had forgotten the $a_j$ in the hurry, but the next result still holds. Sorry again, I will be much more clear next time.

Comment: No problem, thanks for bringing me up to speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remark that $X\in M_p(F_p)$ and the equation in the unknown $Y$  is linear; consequently, if there exists a solution $Y\in M_p(\overline{F_p})$, then there exists a solution in $M_p(F_p)$.

Proposition 1. Necessarily, $X$ is either nilpotent or invertible.

Proof. By recurrence, we show that, for every positive integer $k$,$YX^k-X^kY=kX^k$. We deduce that, for $1\leq k<p$, $tr(X^k)=0$. Using the Newton's formulae, we obtain that the characteristic polynomial of $X$ is in the form $x^p-\alpha$ where $\alpha\in F_p$ and we are done.

Proposition 2. Every nilpotent matrix $X$ works.

Proof. Note that the Jordan form of $X$ is over $F_p$. Then it suffices to consider the case when  $X$ is a nilpotent Jordan block of dimension $k\leq p$. Then a solution is $Y=diag(k-1,k-2,\cdots,0)$.

Proposition 3. Among the invertible matrices $X$, work only those that are similar to a matrix of the form $\alpha I_p+J_p$ where $\alpha\in F_p\setminus 0$ and $J_p$ is the nilpotent Jordan block.

Proof. Since $X$ is invertible, $X^p-\alpha I_p=(X-\alpha I_p)^p=0$ and $X$ is in the form $\alpha I_p+N$ where $N$ is nilpotent and $\alpha\in F_p\setminus 0$. Then $YX-XY=YN-NY=\alpha I_p+N$. By recurrence, $YN^k-N^kY=k(\alpha N^{k-1}+N^k)$. Suppose that there is $k\leq p-1$ s.t. $N^k=0,N^{k-1}\not=0$; then $k\alpha N^{k-1}=0$, a contradiction. Then we may assume that $N=J_p$, the nilpotent Jordan block of dimension $p$.

A solution $Y$ is the $2$-band matrix defined, for every admissible $i$, by $Y_{ii}=p-i,Y_{i+1,i}=(p-i)\alpha$.